# drupal------how to output it

Tags: php, drupal

this is the code in my module file. if i only want to print the second or the third value or another value., how should i do?

```
function alterlink_address(){   //page callback function
$sql = db_query("SELECT field_link_url FROM {content_type_address}");
while ($q = db_fetch_object($sql)){

return $q->field_link_url.'<br>';
```

}
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no drupal expert and there will surely be a more economic way, but this will still work:

```
function alterlink_address(){   //page callback function
   $sql = db_query("SELECT field_link_url FROM {content_type_address}");
   while ($q = db_fetch_object($sql)){
      $results[] = $q->field_link_url.'<br>';
   } 
   return $results[0]."<br />";
}
```

Where the 0 in square brackets is the number (starting from 0) of the result you want to return.

A couple of notes:

1. a correct indentation can save lives;
2. getting a plethora of results from the database and displaying just a few of them is a nice method to awaken Cthulhu. I suggest you take a look at the drupal docs to get directly just the results you need.